# How is the usage of "guy" different from "man"/"boy" in these sentences?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

The word "guy" being used other than with an adjective seems odd to my ears. Is there a rule or explanation as to why that is?

These sentences sound ok with either "guy" or "man" or "boy":

- He's a big guy/man/boy
- That guy/man/boy is looks tired (That being the adjective here)

Whereas these don't. Replacing "guy" with "boy" or "man" seems more natural :

- A guy is coming this way
- One guy is enough to bring the wall down

EDIT: Is it all about familiarity? If you know the man or if at least, it's a specific man, "guy" seems to fit. In the example "A man is coming this way", you presumably don't know the man. In "One man is enough to [do X]", it's not about a specific man. *Any* man could do X. And more often than not, you'd use some form of an adjective for a known or specific person, which ties back to my feeling about the adjectives..

Comment: If I get a close vote citing "Primarily opinion based" as the reason, should I take it to mean that there isn't a rule regarding this, and the oddity is to my ears alone? (and a few others perhaps)

Comment: 'That' is a distal demonstrative determiner here, 'a' the indefinite article, and 'one' a numeral. The only relevant adjective is 'big', and that comes after an indefinite article. // 'He's big man/fellow/cissy...'  and 'Woman / Girl / Dog looks [/is] tired' are unacceptable, and 'Men / Women / Bulldozers are enough to bring the wall down' have a different meaning.

Comment: May be my focus on adjectives was misguided. I've rephrased to address my broader question.

Comment: Presumably, *[a guy is coming](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%E2%80%9CA+guy+is+coming%E2%80%9D)*  sounded fine in these cases.

Comment: @user9825893y50932 In the example `".. if he'd said stay home, a guy is coming by, I'd have fallen for it.. "` seems a little bit along the lines of "a guy is coming by to fix the TV" or "I have a guy to arrange my travels", which in my head, translates to "TV guy" or "Travel guy", and sounds normal. 

But in the other example, `But if a guy is coming out, people gonna take the negative outlook first` is any random guy, and this does indeed sound odd to me. (There is an "are" missing between people and gonna, so I don't know reliable this is)

May be it's all my imagination, I don't know.

Comment: 'A guy is coming this way' seems to mix two registers, which always sounds incongruous. 'A man is coming' and 'Some guy's coming' are in obviously different, but internally consistent, registers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not sure I follow. Is "guy" an informal register, and is "A" a formal one? Feel free to replace "formal" with "familiar" here.

Comment: 'Guy' is not, nowadays (if it ever was), masculine.

Comment: @NigelJ "Guys" is definitely not always masculine, but I still think the singular, "guy", is. Except in cases of TV guy, cable guy, pizza guy, which are just like chairman, postman, cameraman - traditionally jobs for men, but really applied to women too. Specifically feminine terms like camerawoman, and gender neutral terms like chairperson are pretty new (and well justified).

Comment: I switched to 'Some guy is coming' because I think it sounds more likely that 'a guy is coming'. 'A guy' and 'coming this way' are, in my opinion, in different registers. Of course, replacing 'coming this way' by 'comin' this way' changes things.

Comment: Sorry but the only difference boy/guy/man should make is alphabetical.